# SonarTS deprecation error when injector is used

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using angular 5. I am using injector to inject one of my sevices like following

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  handleError(error) {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);
}
```

Everything works fine. But when sonar tests are run it throws an error saying

> get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type or InjectionToken

How to resolve this error ? I dont see any documentation regarding the deprecation !! . Thanks in advance.

Comment: try writing it as `this.injector.get<Router>(Router)`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response ! My sonar scanner ran today and it still shows the same issue !!

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.injector.get<NgControl>(NgControl as any);
```

this is the new way from v4.0.0